# create an array dynamically in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
Array
(
    [pagination] => Array
        (
            [next_url] => https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/1/followed-by?access_token=421
        )
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [username] => iambiswajit
                )
             [1] => Array
                (
                    [username] => iambiswajit
                )   
        )
)
```

i have the above array and have displayed the first array in the first page then stored the next_url in first session and carried it to next page

```
if(empty($followers['pagination']))
    {
        //code
    }
else
    {
        $list= $followers['pagination']['next_url'];
        $followedby2 = file_get_contents("$list");
        $followers2 = @json_decode($followedby2, true);
        $_SESSION["followers2"] = $followers2;

        ?><footer>
            <div class="submit_link">
                <a href="a_follower_nextlist.php"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next" class="alt_btn"></a>
            </div>
        </footer><?
    }
```

Went to a_follower_nextlist.php page and processed the second array in that first session and then gave a next button and through this button called the same page  like this

```
if(empty($followers['pagination']))
    {
        //code
    }
else
    {
        $list= $followers['pagination']['next_url'];
        $followedby2 = file_get_contents("$list");
        $followers2 = @json_decode($followedby2, true);
        $_SESSION["followers2"] = $followers2;

        ?><footer>
            <div class="submit_link">
                <a href="#"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Previous" class="alt_btn"></a>
            </div>

            <div class="submit_link">
                <a href="a_follower_nextlist.php"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next" class="alt_btn"></a>
            </div>
        </footer><?
    }
```

BUT here i have called the same page to get the next url, so basically i get the entire list in 2 page no matter what the list is.

Now i am planning to create a previous button. for this i wish to create an array where i can store all the session variable in separate index value and then display according to the position value on the click of previous button. but i am having problem in creating the array. can anyone please help

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are having trouble doing is not so much forming an array structure but in tracking your location within the array.

Storing an array pointer might be the way to go.

Also on rereading you post I notice that you are storing the data in the session cookie which is fine if you want to do that. However are you also unsetting the data once you are done with it? Otherwise it will hang about from one page to the next being as it is in the session cookie.